# How to write this statement in Laravel model class

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter-2

How do i write such a statement in Laravel Model class

```
SELECT * from video where view=(select max(view) from video)

$query = DB::table('video')->select('*');

$alldetails = $query->addSelect('max(view)')->get();
```

I intend selecting all the attribute of the video with the maximum amount of views

**My Model**

```
class Video extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    protected $table = 'video';

    public static function feature(){
        $query = DB::table('video')->select('*');
        $alldetails = $query->addSelect('max(view)')->get();
        return $alldetails;
    }
}
```

**My Controller**

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {
    public function home(){
        $feature=View::feature();

        return View::make('frontend/index')
        ->with("title","Kromatik Multimedia")
        ->with('feature'.$feature);
    }
}
```

**My View**

```
@foreach($feature as $fet)
    $fet->title;
@endforeach
```

Comment: I can help, but can you explain what your query is trying to do? Are you trying to get the video with the most views?

Comment: yes that is exactly what 1 am trying to do

Comment: WereWolf beat me to it. His answer will do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a model like this:

```
class Video extends Eloquent {

    // Laravel expects the table name "videos"
    // for Video model so need to specify here
    // because you didn't follow that convention

    protected $table = 'video';

}
```

From your controller call something like this:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController {

    public function home()
    {
        // Get the Video model with maximum views; assumed that,
        // view field contains numeric number, i.e. 2 (two views)
        $featured = Video::orderBy('view', 'desc')->first();

        // Load the "index.blade.php" view from "views/frontend" folder
        return View::make('frontend.index')->with('video', $featured);
    }
}
```

In the `view` (No need to loop because only one model is passed):

```
{{ $video->title }}
{{ $video->genre }}
```